# Как переключить Google Play Console с русского на английский язык?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Хотя бы для того, чтобы читать проблемные сообщения на английском языке и искать на них ответы в англоязычных ресурсах.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В интерфейсе консоли администратора используется язык, который вы выбрали в настройках аккаунта.

> Чтобы изменить язык своего аккаунта Google, выполните следующие
>   действия:
>
> 1. Перейдите на страницу настроек аккаунта Google.
> 2. Найдите раздел Инструменты.
> 3. Нажмите Языковые настройки.
> 4. Чтобы изменить язык, нажмите на значок Изменить.
> 5. Выберите язык из раскрывающегося списка и нажмите ОК.
>
> Примечание. Чтобы выбрать несколько языков, нажмите Добавить язык на
>   странице языковых настроек.
>
> Изменив язык интерфейса, закройте браузер. Затем снова запустите
>   браузер и проверьте, отобразились ли изменения в настройках аккаунта.

[Отсюда](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047)

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!